# What if size argument for std::vector::resize is equal to the current size?

Tags: c++, vector, containers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Reading the manual about vector::resize http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

It only says what happens if the size is greater or smaller, but does not say what happens if it's equal. Is it guaranteed that on equal size it will not reallocate the array and invalidate the iterators?

I wanted to avoid one branch and handle only 2 cases (>= or <) instead of 3 (< or > or ==), but if resizing to same size is undefined, then i will have to check that case too.

Comment: Given the info in the part "Exception safety", you can safely assume there is no reallocation on resize with the size being equal the the current size of the vector.

Comment: The std::vector<> class is a template class, so you have the source code on your computer. You could look for yourself. Or you could write a test program and debug that. Or look at the assembler code that is generated. Or make a vector of a class that prints information when the copy constructor and/or the move constructor is called, and then see what happens. Besides that, I'm pretty sure that this case is checked in the vector's implementation and nothing is done then.

Comment: Don't read cplusplus.com, it's known to be wrong on several occassions.

Comment: @n.m. note that in this case also cppreference is not clear on iterator invalidation. It has a note that "Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators, ..." but its not clearly states what iterators are invalidated in general

Comment: If "same-size resizing" had any effect at all, it would be time for the entire C++ committee and the language implementers to retire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably just an error in the linked reference. The standard says [following](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#capacity-14):

> `void resize(size_type sz);`
>
> *Effects*: If `sz < size()`, erases the last `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.

Since `sz - size()` is `0` in your case, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

From [`[vector]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#capacity-14)

> Effects: If `sz < size()`, erases the last `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.

In the case that `size() == sz` it inserts 0 elements into the sequence, which is the same as doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Now, probably most implementations are sufficiently intelligent about the case where nothing needs to be done and will literally do nothing.

But I am asking myself, you are intending to call resize, why are you holding iterators anyway? Basically, you should never hold iterators for any longer time, especially when containers may get resized. Just write your algorithms in ways that don't need to hold iterators over the resize point.

I am guessing wildly here, but maybe you are not using the right container and more context about what you are trying to achieve may result in a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<>` implementation:

```
void resize(size_type __new_size)
{
    if (__new_size > size())
        _M_default_append(__new_size - size());
    else if (__new_size < size())
        _M_erase_at_end(this->_M_impl._M_start + __new_size);
}
```

So, as expected: It does nothing.

Edit:
Taken from my RHEL server, g++ and C++ library package version 5.3.

Comment: thats one possible implementation (you should give a reference where you took it from btw), but you cannot conclude that every implementation has to behave like that only because this one does

Comment: Unfortunately, my code will be compiling for several different architectures with different compilers, i cannot rely on what i can find in headers on my current computer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're asking if iterators will be invalidated when `resize(size())` is called.  The answer is no, iterators will not be invalidated.  Probably very little will happen at all, but certainly not iterator invalidation, because that only happens when the storage has to be reallocated, which would never happen if the resize is a no-op.