# Is it legal to call resize(0) on an empty std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v; // v has no elements
int size = getSomeNumber(); // this function may return any number that is >= 0
v.resize(size);
```

As you can see, `getSomeNumber` may return any positivie number or 0.

Instead of checking if `size > 0` before calling `resize`, I would rather simply call it immediately. And in case `size` is 0, nothing would happen.

Is this legal code?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447386/what-if-size-argument-for-stdvectorresize-is-equal-to-the-current-size

Comment: If the size is the same, then nothing happens. Why would the stdlib do anything else? It doesn't go out of its way to shoot you in the foot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if size argument for std::vector::resize is equal to the current size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447386/what-if-size-argument-for-stdvectorresize-is-equal-to-the-current-size)

Comment: why would it not be legal code? How would you resize a vector with eg 100 elements to size 0 if not via `resize(0)` ? (... ok you could call `clear`, but there is no reason to disallow `resize(0)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is legal to call `resize(0)` on an empty `std::vector`.

Although `std::vector::clear` does the same thing, and is clearer.

Note that you can regard the behaviour of `v.resize(v.size())` to be a no operation. The C++ standard states that the complexity has to be linear (n.b. not necessarily *proportional*) in the difference between the new size and the current size in the cases where the operation doesn't decrease the number of elements.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP doesn't know whether the argument of `resize` will be 0.

Comment: @DanielLangr: It answers the title.

Comment: Agree, just suggesting OP to use `clear` is a bit off-topic from the perspective of their problem.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yeah, it's worth fluffing up the answer up a bit. Interesting that the standard doesn't mention the equal case explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It's legal, as @Bathsheba said it has the same effect of calling the `clear()` method. Also, it is guaranteed no exception is thrown: *"If n is less than or equal to the size of the container, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee)."* ([reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)).

Comment: Please, do not use the reference from cplusplus.com. It's not very precise and sometimes it contains bugs or outdated information. As for exceptions, look [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#capacity-16). (For illustration, cplusplus does not reflect new C++17 functions for `std::map`, and seems to be missing C++17 stuff entirely.)